# Random update without where

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working on a project, and we've been having trouble with a bug that seems to be randomly updating all records of a model in the database when it shouldn't be. We've looked at the logs and we can see SQL updates being called without where clauses, which obviously are the culprit, but we don't know why it's happening. We don't call update_all anywhere.

Our best guess is that a single model is being passed somewhere that is expecting a collection and that is causing unexpected behaviour, but so far we've been unable to find where this happens.

Are there any other common mistakes that may be causing this behavior? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is possibility that you use callbacks some where in your model

Comment: You might want to install the `active_record_query_trace` gem; it will give you a backtrace for every SQL query that's executed by the Rails app.